# Как разместить гифку на Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, gif

Я создаю игру, и в моей игре, когда `HERO` стоит рядом с `MONSTER`, будет отображаться гифка, чтобы напугать игрока. Но я не знаю, как это сделать. Пытался поставить PHP или HTML код, но не работает ... Функция - `AtualizaTela2()`. Это мой основной код:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hero's Escape Game</title>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

var objCanvas=null; // object that represents the canvas
var objContexto=null; 

// Hero positioning control
var xHero=300;
var yHero=100;

// Monster positioning control
var xMonster=620;
var yMonster=0;

var imgFundo2 = new Image();
imgFundo2.src = "Images/Pista2.png";

var imgMonster = new Image();
imgMonster.src = "Images/Monster.png";

var imgHero = new Image();
imgHero.src = "Images/Hero.png";

function AtualizaTela2(){

if((xHero >= xMonster-10)&&(xHero <= xMonster + 10))
{

/*gif here*/

}

objContexto.drawImage(imgFundo2,0,0);
objContexto.drawImage(imgHero, xHero, yHero);
objContexto.drawImage(imgMonster, xMonster, yMonster);

function Iniciar(){

objCanvas = document.getElementById("meuCanvas");
objContexto = objCanvas.getContext("2d");
AtualizaTela2();

}

/* the function HeroMovement() and MonsterMovement() are not here */

}

</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="Iniciar();" onkeydown="HeroMovement(event);">

<canvas id="meuCanvas" width="1233"
height="507"
style="border:1px solid #000000;">
Seu browser não suporta o elemento CANVAS, atualize-se!!!
</canvas><BR>
</body>
</html>
```

Это упрощенный код, потому что реальный код очень большой!

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to put a gif with Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48234696/7394871) от участника  [@Grandtour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9073437/grandtour).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/48234696/7394871

Answer (score 2):

## Загрузка и воспроизведение изображения GIF на canvas.

К сожалению, размер ответа превышен, пришлось удалить большую часть подробных комментариев к коду.

Я не буду вдаваться в подробности, так как весь процесс довольно сложный.

Единственный способ получить анимацию GIF на Canvas - это декодировать изображение GIF в javascript. К счастью, формат не слишком сложен: данные расположены в блоках, которые содержат размер изображения, цветовые палитры, информацию о времени, поле комментариев и способ рисования кадров.

### Пользовательская загрузка и проигрыватель GIF.

В приведенном ниже примере содержится объект с именем GIF, который будет создавать изображения GIF пользовательского формата из URL-адресов, которые могут воспроизводить GIF аналогично тому, как воспроизводится видео. Вы также можете получить произвольный доступ ко всем кадрам GIF в любом порядке.

Есть много обратных вызовов и вариантов. В комментариях есть основная информация об использовании, а в коде показано, как загрузить гифку. Есть функции для паузы и воспроизведения, поиска (timeInSeconds) и seekFrame (frameNumber), свойства для управления playSpeed и многое другое. Нет никаких событий переключения, так как доступ осуществляется немедленно.

```
var myGif = GIF();
 myGif.load("GIFurl.gif");
```

После загрузки

`ctx.drawImage(myGif.image,0,0); // will draw the playing gif image`

Или получить доступ к кадрам через буфер кадров

`ctx.drawImage(myGif.frames[0].image,0,0); // draw frame 0 only.`

Перейдите к нижней части объекта GIF, чтобы увидеть все параметры с комментариями.

GIF должен принадлежать к тому же домену или иметь заголовок CORS.

GIF в демоверсии взят из [wiki commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Wax_fire.gif) и содержит более 250 кадров, некоторые устройства низкого уровня будут иметь с этим проблемы, поскольку каждый кадр преобразуется в полное изображение RGBA, что делает загруженный GIF значительно больше, чем размер файла GIF.

### Демо

Загружает гифку, отображающую количество кадров и количество кадров как загруженные. При загрузке 100 частиц каждая с кадрами произвольного доступа, воспроизводящимися с независимыми скоростями и независимыми направлениями, отображаются в фоновом режиме.

Изображение переднего плана - это гифка, воспроизводимая с частотой кадров, встроенной в файл.

Код такой, как есть, только в качестве примера, а НЕ для коммерческого использования.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var myGif;
// Can not load gif cross domain unless it has CORS header
const gifURL = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a2/Wax_fire.gif";
// timeout just waits till script has been parsed and executed
// then starts loading a gif
setTimeout(()=>{
    myGif = GIF();                  // creates a new gif  
    myGif.onerror = function(e){
       console.log("Gif loading error " + e.type);
    }
    myGif.load(gifURL);  

},0); 
// Function draws an image
function drawImage(image,x,y,scale,rot){
    ctx.setTransform(scale,0,0,scale,x,y);
    ctx.rotate(rot);
    ctx.drawImage(image,-image.width / 2, -image.height / 2);
}
// helper functions
const rand  = (min = 1, max = min + (min = 0)) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
const setOf     =(c,C)=>{var a=[],i=0;while(i<c){a.push(C(i++))}return a};
const eachOf    =(a,C)=>{var i=0;const l=a.length;while(i<l && C(a[i],i++,l)!==true);return i};
const mod = (v,m) => ((v % m) + m) % m;

// create 100 particles
const particles = setOf(100,() => {
    return {
      x : rand(innerWidth),
      y : rand(innerHeight),
      scale : rand(0.15, 0.5),
      rot : rand(Math.PI * 2),
      frame : 0,
      frameRate : rand(-2,2),
      dr : rand(-0.1,0.1),
      dx : rand(-4,4),
      dy : rand(-4,4),
   };
});
// Animate and draw 100 particles
function drawParticles(){
  eachOf(particles, part => {
     part.x += part.dx;
     part.y += part.dy;
     part.rot += part.dr;
     part.frame += part.frameRate;
     part.x = mod(part.x,innerWidth);
     part.y = mod(part.y,innerHeight);
     var frame = mod(part.frame ,myGif.frames.length) | 0;
 
     drawImage(myGif.frames[frame].image,part.x,part.y,part.scale,part.rot);
  });
}      


var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;
var cw = w / 2; // center 
var ch = h / 2;

// main update function
function update(timer) {
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // reset transform
  if (w !== innerWidth || h !== innerHeight) {
    cw = (w = canvas.width = innerWidth) / 2;
    ch = (h = canvas.height = innerHeight) / 2;
  } else {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  }
  if(myGif) { // If gif object defined
    if(!myGif.loading){  // if loaded
        // draw random access to gif frames
        drawParticles();
        drawImage(myGif.image,cw,ch,1,0); // displays the current frame.
    }else if(myGif.lastFrame !== null){  // Shows frames as they load
        ctx.drawImage(myGif.lastFrame.image,0,0); 
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillText("GIF loading frame " + myGif.frames.length ,10,21);
        ctx.fillText("GIF loading frame " + myGif.frames.length,10,19);
        ctx.fillText("GIF loading frame " + myGif.frames.length,9,20);
        ctx.fillText("GIF loading frame " + myGif.frames.length,11,20);
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillText("GIF loading frame " + myGif.frames.length,10,20);
        
    }
  
  }else{
        ctx.fillText("Waiting for GIF image ",10,20);
  
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);

/*============================================================================
  Gif Decoder and player for use with Canvas API's

**NOT** for commercial use.

To use

    var myGif = GIF();                  // creates a new gif  
    var myGif = new GIF();              // will work as well but not needed as GIF() returns the correct reference already.    
    myGif.load("myGif.gif");            // set URL and load
    myGif.onload = function(event){     // fires when loading is complete
                                        //event.type   = "load"
                                        //event.path   array containing a reference to the gif
    }
    myGif.onprogress = function(event){ // Note this function is not bound to myGif
                                        //event.bytesRead    bytes decoded
                                        //event.totalBytes   total bytes
                                        //event.frame        index of last frame decoded
    }
    myGif.onerror = function(event){    // fires if there is a problem loading. this = myGif
                                        //event.type   a description of the error
                                        //event.path   array containing a reference to the gif
    }

Once loaded the gif can be displayed
    if(!myGif.loading){
        ctx.drawImage(myGif.image,0,0); 
    }
You can display the last frame loaded during loading

    if(myGif.lastFrame !== null){
        ctx.drawImage(myGif.lastFrame.image,0,0); 
    }


To access all the frames
    var gifFrames = myGif.frames; // an array of frames.

A frame holds various frame associated items.
    myGif.frame[0].image; // the first frames image
    myGif.frame[0].delay; // time in milliseconds frame is displayed for




Gifs use various methods to reduce the file size. The loaded frames do not maintain the optimisations and hold the full resolution frames as DOM images. This mean the memory footprint of a decode gif will be many time larger than the Gif file.
 */
const GIF = function () {
    // **NOT** for commercial use.
    var timerID;                          // timer handle for set time out usage
    var st;                               // holds the stream object when loading.
    var interlaceOffsets  = [0, 4, 2, 1]; // used in de-interlacing.
    var interlaceSteps    = [8, 8, 4, 2];
    var interlacedBufSize;  // this holds a buffer to de interlace. Created on the first frame and when size changed
    var deinterlaceBuf;
    var pixelBufSize;    // this holds a buffer for pixels. Created on the first frame and when size changed
    var pixelBuf;
    const GIF_FILE = { // gif file data headers
        GCExt   : 0xF9,
        COMMENT : 0xFE,
        APPExt  : 0xFF,
        UNKNOWN : 0x01, // not sure what this is but need to skip it in parser
        IMAGE   : 0x2C,
        EOF     : 59,   // This is entered as decimal
        EXT     : 0x21,
    };      
    // simple buffered stream used to read from the file 
    var Stream = function (data) { 
        this.data = new Uint8ClampedArray(data);
        this.pos  = 0;
        var len   = this.data.length;
        this.getString = function (count) { // returns a string from current pos of len count
            var s = "";
            while (count--) { s += String.fromCharCode(this.data[this.pos++]) }
            return s;
        };
        this.readSubBlocks = function () { // reads a set of blocks as a string
            var size, count, data  = "";
            do {
                count = size = this.data[this.pos++];
                while (count--) { data += String.fromCharCode(this.data[this.pos++]) }
            } while (size !== 0 && this.pos < len);
            return data;
        }
        this.readSubBlocksB = function () { // reads a set of blocks as binary
            var size, count, data = [];
            do {
                count = size = this.data[this.pos++];
                while (count--) { data.push(this.data[this.pos++]);}
            } while (size !== 0 && this.pos < len);
            return data;
        }
    };
    // LZW decoder uncompressed each frames pixels
    // this needs to be optimised.
    // minSize is the min dictionary as powers of two
    // size and data is the compressed pixels
    function lzwDecode(minSize, data) {
        var i, pixelPos, pos, clear, eod, size, done, dic, code, last, d, len;
        pos = pixelPos = 0;
        dic      = [];
        clear    = 1 << minSize;
        eod      = clear + 1;
        size     = minSize + 1;
        done     = false;
        while (!done) { // JavaScript optimisers like a clear exit though I never use 'done' apart from fooling the optimiser
            last = code;
            code = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                if (data[pos >> 3] & (1 << (pos & 7))) { code |= 1 << i }
                pos++;
            }
            if (code === clear) { // clear and reset the dictionary
                dic = [];
                size = minSize + 1;
                for (i = 0; i < clear; i++) { dic[i] = [i] }
                dic[clear] = [];
                dic[eod] = null;
            } else {
                if (code === eod) {  done = true; return }
                if (code >= dic.length) { dic.push(dic[last].concat(dic[last][0])) }
                else if (last !== clear) { dic.push(dic[last].concat(dic[code][0])) }
                d = dic[code];
                len = d.length;
                for (i = 0; i < len; i++) { pixelBuf[pixelPos++] = d[i] }
                if (dic.length === (1 << size) && size < 12) { size++ }
            }
        }
    };
    function parseColourTable(count) { // get a colour table of length count  Each entry is 3 bytes, for RGB.
        var colours = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) { colours.push([st.data[st.pos++], st.data[st.pos++], st.data[st.pos++]]) }
        return colours;
    }
    function parse (){        // read the header. This is the starting point of the decode and async calls parseBlock
        var bitField;
        st.pos                += 6;  
        gif.width             = (st.data[st.pos++]) + ((st.data[st.pos++]) << 8);
        gif.height            = (st.data[st.pos++]) + ((st.data[st.pos++]) << 8);
        bitField              = st.data[st.pos++];
        gif.colorRes          = (bitField & 0b1110000) >> 4;
        gif.globalColourCount = 1 << ((bitField & 0b111) + 1);
        gif.bgColourIndex     = st.data[st.pos++];
        st.pos++;                    // ignoring pixel aspect ratio. if not 0, aspectRatio = (pixelAspectRatio + 15) / 64
        if (bitField & 0b10000000) { gif.globalColourTable = parseColourTable(gif.globalColourCount) } // global colour flag
        setTimeout(parseBlock, 0);
    }
    function parseAppExt() { // get application specific data. Netscape added iterations and terminator. Ignoring that
        st.pos += 1;
        if ('NETSCAPE' === st.getString(8)) { st.pos += 8 }  // ignoring this data. iterations (word) and terminator (byte)
        else {
            st.pos += 3;            // 3 bytes of string usually "2.0" when identifier is NETSCAPE
            st.readSubBlocks();     // unknown app extension
        }
    };
    function parseGCExt() { // get GC data
        var bitField;
        st.pos++;
        bitField              = st.data[st.pos++];
        gif.disposalMethod    = (bitField & 0b11100) >> 2;
        gif.transparencyGiven = bitField & 0b1 ? true : false; // ignoring bit two that is marked as  userInput???
        gif.delayTime         = (st.data[st.pos++]) + ((st.data[st.pos++]) << 8);
        gif.transparencyIndex = st.data[st.pos++];
        st.pos++;
    };
    function parseImg() {                           // decodes image data to create the indexed pixel image
        var deinterlace, frame, bitField;
        deinterlace = function (width) {                   // de interlace pixel data if needed
            var lines, fromLine, pass, toline;
            lines = pixelBufSize / width;
            fromLine = 0;
            if (interlacedBufSize !== pixelBufSize) {      // create the buffer if size changed or undefined.
                deinterlaceBuf = new Uint8Array(pixelBufSize);
                interlacedBufSize = pixelBufSize;
            }
            for (pass = 0; pass < 4; pass++) {
                for (toLine = interlaceOffsets[pass]; toLine < lines; toLine += interlaceSteps[pass]) {
                    deinterlaceBuf.set(pixelBuf.subArray(fromLine, fromLine + width), toLine * width);
                    fromLine += width;
                }
            }
        };
        frame                = {}
        gif.frames.push(frame);
        frame.disposalMethod = gif.disposalMethod;
        frame.time           = gif.length;
        frame.delay          = gif.delayTime * 10;
        gif.length          += frame.delay;
        if (gif.transparencyGiven) { frame.transparencyIndex = gif.transparencyIndex }
        else { frame.transparencyIndex = undefined }
        frame.leftPos = (st.data[st.pos++]) + ((st.data[st.pos++]) << 8);
        frame.topPos  = (st.data[st.pos++]) + ((st.data[st.pos++]) << 8);
        frame.width   = (st.data[st.pos++]) + ((st.data[st.pos++]) << 8);
        frame.height  = (st.data[st.pos++]) + ((st.data[st.pos++]) << 8);
        bitField      = st.data[st.pos++];
        frame.localColourTableFlag = bitField & 0b10000000 ? true : false; 
        if (frame.localColourTableFlag) { frame.localColourTable = parseColourTable(1 << ((bitField & 0b111) + 1)) }
        if (pixelBufSize !== frame.width * frame.height) { // create a pixel buffer if not yet created or if current frame size is different from previous
            pixelBuf     = new Uint8Array(frame.width * frame.height);
            pixelBufSize = frame.width * frame.height;
        }
        lzwDecode(st.data[st.pos++], st.readSubBlocksB()); // decode the pixels
        if (bitField & 0b1000000) {                        // de interlace if needed
            frame.interlaced = true;
            deinterlace(frame.width);
        } else { frame.interlaced = false }
        processFrame(frame);                               // convert to canvas image
    };
    function processFrame(frame) { // creates a RGBA canvas image from the indexed pixel data.
        var ct, cData, dat, pixCount, ind, useT, i, pixel, pDat, col, frame, ti;
        frame.image        = document.createElement('canvas');
        frame.image.width  = gif.width;
        frame.image.height = gif.height;
        frame.image.ctx    = frame.image.getContext("2d");
        ct = frame.localColourTableFlag ? frame.localColourTable : gif.globalColourTable;
        if (gif.lastFrame === null) { gif.lastFrame = frame }
        useT = (gif.lastFrame.disposalMethod === 2 || gif.lastFrame.disposalMethod === 3) ? true : false;
        if (!useT) { frame.image.ctx.drawImage(gif.lastFrame.image, 0, 0, gif.width, gif.height) }
        cData = frame.image.ctx.getImageData(frame.leftPos, frame.topPos, frame.width, frame.height);
        ti  = frame.transparencyIndex;
        dat = cData.data;
        if (frame.interlaced) { pDat = deinterlaceBuf }
        else { pDat = pixelBuf }
        pixCount = pDat.length;
        ind = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < pixCount; i++) {
            pixel = pDat[i];
            col   = ct[pixel];
            if (ti !== pixel) {
                dat[ind++] = col[0];
                dat[ind++] = col[1];
                dat[ind++] = col[2];
                dat[ind++] = 255;      // Opaque.
            } else
                if (useT) {
                    dat[ind + 3] = 0; // Transparent.
                    ind += 4;
                } else { ind += 4 }
        }
        frame.image.ctx.putImageData(cData, frame.leftPos, frame.topPos);
        gif.lastFrame = frame;
        if (!gif.waitTillDone && typeof gif.onload === "function") { doOnloadEvent() }// if !waitTillDone the call onload now after first frame is loaded
    };
    // **NOT** for commercial use.
    function finnished() { // called when the load has completed
        gif.loading           = false;
        gif.frameCount        = gif.frames.length;
        gif.lastFrame         = null;
        st                    = undefined;
        gif.complete          = true;
        gif.disposalMethod    = undefined;
        gif.transparencyGiven = undefined;
        gif.delayTime         = undefined;
        gif.transparencyIndex = undefined;
        gif.waitTillDone      = undefined;
        pixelBuf              = undefined; // dereference pixel buffer
        deinterlaceBuf        = undefined; // dereference interlace buff (may or may not be used);
        pixelBufSize          = undefined;
        deinterlaceBuf        = undefined;
        gif.currentFrame      = 0;
        if (gif.frames.length > 0) { gif.image = gif.frames[0].image }
        doOnloadEvent();
        if (typeof gif.onloadall === "function") {
            (gif.onloadall.bind(gif))({   type : 'loadall', path : [gif] });
        }
        if (gif.playOnLoad) { gif.play() }
    }
    function canceled () { // called if the load has been cancelled
        finnished();
        if (typeof gif.cancelCallback === "function") { (gif.cancelCallback.bind(gif))({ type : 'canceled', path : [gif] }) }
    }
    function parseExt() {              // parse extended blocks
        const blockID = st.data[st.pos++];
        if(blockID === GIF_FILE.GCExt) { parseGCExt() }
        else if(blockID === GIF_FILE.COMMENT) { gif.comment += st.readSubBlocks() }
        else if(blockID === GIF_FILE.APPExt) { parseAppExt() }
        else {
            if(blockID === GIF_FILE.UNKNOWN) { st.pos += 13; } // skip unknow block
            st.readSubBlocks();
        }

    }
    function parseBlock() { // parsing the blocks
        if (gif.cancel !== undefined && gif.cancel === true) { canceled(); return }

        const blockId = st.data[st.pos++];
        if(blockId === GIF_FILE.IMAGE ){ // image block
            parseImg();
            if (gif.firstFrameOnly) { finnished(); return }
        }else if(blockId === GIF_FILE.EOF) { finnished(); return }
        else { parseExt() }
        if (typeof gif.onprogress === "function") {
            gif.onprogress({ bytesRead  : st.pos, totalBytes : st.data.length, frame : gif.frames.length });
        }
        setTimeout(parseBlock, 0); // parsing frame async so processes can get some time in.
    };
    function cancelLoad(callback) { // cancels the loading. This will cancel the load before the next frame is decoded
        if (gif.complete) { return false }
        gif.cancelCallback = callback;
        gif.cancel         = true;
        return true;
    }
    function error(type) {
        if (typeof gif.onerror === "function") { (gif.onerror.bind(this))({ type : type, path : [this] }) }
        gif.onload  = gif.onerror = undefined;
        gif.loading = false;
    }
    function doOnloadEvent() { // fire onload event if set
        gif.currentFrame = 0;
        gif.nextFrameAt  = gif.lastFrameAt  = new Date().valueOf(); // just sets the time now
        if (typeof gif.onload === "function") { (gif.onload.bind(gif))({ type : 'load', path : [gif] }) }
        gif.onerror = gif.onload  = undefined;
    }
    function dataLoaded(data) { // Data loaded create stream and parse
        st = new Stream(data);
        parse();
    }
    function loadGif(filename) { // starts the load
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.responseType = "arraybuffer";
        ajax.onload = function (e) {
            if (e.target.status === 404) { error("File not found") }
            else if(e.target.status >= 200 && e.target.status < 300 ) { dataLoaded(ajax.response) }
            else { error("Loading error : " + e.target.status) }
        };
        ajax.open('GET', filename, true);
        ajax.send();
        ajax.onerror = function (e) { error("File error") };
        this.src = filename;
        this.loading = true;
    }
    function play() { // starts play if paused
        if (!gif.playing) {
            gif.paused  = false;
            gif.playing = true;
            playing();
        }
    }
    function pause() { // stops play
        gif.paused  = true;
        gif.playing = false;
        clearTimeout(timerID);
    }
    function togglePlay(){
        if(gif.paused || !gif.playing){ gif.play() }
        else{ gif.pause() }
    }
    function seekFrame(frame) { // seeks to frame number.
        clearTimeout(timerID);
        gif.currentFrame = frame % gif.frames.length;
        if (gif.playing) { playing() }
        else { gif.image = gif.frames[gif.currentFrame].image }
    }
    function seek(time) { // time in Seconds  // seek to frame that would be displayed at time
        clearTimeout(timerID);
        if (time < 0) { time = 0 }
        time *= 1000; // in ms
        time %= gif.length;
        var frame = 0;
        while (time > gif.frames[frame].time + gif.frames[frame].delay && frame < gif.frames.length) {  frame += 1 }
        gif.currentFrame = frame;
        if (gif.playing) { playing() }
        else { gif.image = gif.frames[gif.currentFrame].image}
    }
    function playing() {
        var delay;
        var frame;
        if (gif.playSpeed === 0) {
            gif.pause();
            return;
        } else {
            if (gif.playSpeed < 0) {
                gif.currentFrame -= 1;
                if (gif.currentFrame < 0) {gif.currentFrame = gif.frames.length - 1 }
                frame = gif.currentFrame;
                frame -= 1;
                if (frame < 0) {  frame = gif.frames.length - 1 }
                delay = -gif.frames[frame].delay * 1 / gif.playSpeed;
            } else {
                gif.currentFrame += 1;
                gif.currentFrame %= gif.frames.length;
                delay = gif.frames[gif.currentFrame].delay * 1 / gif.playSpeed;
            }
            gif.image = gif.frames[gif.currentFrame].image;
            timerID = setTimeout(playing, delay);
        }
    }
    var gif = {                      // the gif image object
        onload         : null,       // fire on load. Use waitTillDone = true to have load fire at end or false to fire on first frame
        onerror        : null,       // fires on error
        onprogress     : null,       // fires a load progress event
        onloadall      : null,       // event fires when all frames have loaded and gif is ready
        paused         : false,      // true if paused
        playing        : false,      // true if playing
        waitTillDone   : true,       // If true onload will fire when all frames loaded, if false, onload will fire when first frame has loaded
        loading        : false,      // true if still loading
        firstFrameOnly : false,      // if true only load the first frame
        width          : null,       // width in pixels
        height         : null,       // height in pixels
        frames         : [],         // array of frames
        comment        : "",         // comments if found in file. Note I remember that some gifs have comments per frame if so this will be all comment concatenated
        length         : 0,          // gif length in ms (1/1000 second)
        currentFrame   : 0,          // current frame. 
        frameCount     : 0,          // number of frames
        playSpeed      : 1,          // play speed 1 normal, 2 twice 0.5 half, -1 reverse etc...
        lastFrame      : null,       // temp hold last frame loaded so you can display the gif as it loads
        image          : null,       // the current image at the currentFrame
        playOnLoad     : true,       // if true starts playback when loaded
        // functions
        load           : loadGif,    // call this to load a file
        cancel         : cancelLoad, // call to stop loading
        play           : play,       // call to start play
        pause          : pause,      // call to pause
        seek           : seek,       // call to seek to time
        seekFrame      : seekFrame,  // call to seek to frame
        togglePlay     : togglePlay, // call to toggle play and pause state
    };
    return gif;
}
```

```css
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

ПРИМЕЧАНИЯ

Это работает для 99% гифок. Иногда вы можете встретить гифку, которая воспроизводится некорректно. Причина: (Я никогда не удосужился выяснить). Исправлено: перекодировать gif с помощью современного кодировщика.

Есть незначительные несоответствия, которые необходимо исправить. Со временем я предоставлю пример codePen с ES6 и улучшенным интерфейсом.

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48348567/7394871) от участника  [@Blindman67](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3877726/blindman67).</sub>

Comment: что-то не видно примера на codepen :)

Comment: @Grundy а не было в авторском топике примера на codepen

Comment: А я про него и говорил :) Похоже за три года что-то не срослось :)

Answer (score 2):

Вот и все: вам нужно будет извлечь каждый фрейм и сделать из них массив разделенных фреймов: http://gifgifs.com/split/

проще, если у вас есть URL-адреса или путь, например http://lol.com/Img1.png ...... http://lol.com/Img27.png, с помощью которого вы можете выполнить простой цикл, например:

```js
function drawAnimatedImage(arr,x,y,angle,factor,changespeed) {
    if (!factor) {
        factor = 1;
    }
    if (!changespeed) {
        changespeed = 1;
    }
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(x, y);
    ctx.rotate(angle * Math.PI / 180);
    if (!!arr[Math.round(Date.now()/changespeed) % arr.length]) {
    ctx.drawImage(arr[Math.round(Date.now()/changespeed) % arr.length], -(arr[Math.round(Date.now()/changespeed) % arr.length].width * factor / 2), -(arr[Math.round(Date.now()/changespeed) % arr.length].height * factor / 2), arr[Math.round(Date.now()/changespeed) % arr.length].width * factor, arr[Math.round(Date.now()/changespeed) % arr.length].height * factor);
    }
    ctx.restore();
}

    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var waitingWolf = [];
    var url = ["https://i.imgur.com/k3T7psX.gif","https://i.imgur.com/CTSC8FC.gif","https://i.imgur.com/6NHLWKK.gif","https://i.imgur.com/U1u04sY.gif","https://i.imgur.com/4695vnQ.gif","https://i.imgur.com/oDO0YWT.gif","https://i.imgur.com/LqptRh1.gif","https://i.imgur.com/6gTxvul.gif","https://i.imgur.com/ULN5mqK.gif","https://i.imgur.com/RACB9WM.gif","https://i.imgur.com/4TZ6kNi.gif","https://i.imgur.com/9VvlzhK.gif","https://i.imgur.com/nGUnsfW.gif","https://i.imgur.com/2h8vLjK.gif","https://i.imgur.com/ZCdKkF1.gif","https://i.imgur.com/wZmWrYP.gif","https://i.imgur.com/4lhjVSz.gif","https://i.imgur.com/wVO0PbE.gif","https://i.imgur.com/cgGn5tV.gif","https://i.imgur.com/627gH5Y.gif","https://i.imgur.com/sLDSeS7.gif","https://i.imgur.com/1i1QNAs.gif","https://i.imgur.com/V3vDA1A.gif","https://i.imgur.com/Od2psNo.gif","https://i.imgur.com/WKDXFdh.gif","https://i.imgur.com/RlhIjaM.gif","https://i.imgur.com/293hMnm.gif","https://i.imgur.com/ITm0ukT.gif"]
    function setup () {
                for (var i = 0; i < 28; i++) {
                    waitingWolf[i] = new Image();
                    waitingWolf[i].src = url[i];
                }
    }
    setup();
function yop() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,1000,1000)
            if (waitingWolf.length == 28) {
                drawAnimatedImage(waitingWolf,300,100,0,1,60)
            }
requestAnimationFrame(yop);
}
requestAnimationFrame(yop);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="1000">
</canvas>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61378000/7394871) от участника  [@Woold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9727029/woold).</sub>